# How to get default color and style of action buttons in notifications?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-custom-view

I need to create a custom layout for my notification, with android's native look and feel.

I've used these resources for title and text:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification"
```

but I can't find the resources for style and color of action buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colour of the buttons by

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    // Other properties
    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary));
```

It uses the Primary colour.
More in here https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-n-introducing-upgraded-notifications-d4dd98a7ca92

Comment: Does no longer work in 2023